# Flutter can not fix bottom overflowed when using SafeArea

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I try to use SafeArea with my code but when i rotate the screen the bottom overflowed issue was occured. I try to fix it by using SingleChildScrollView and ListView but it doesn't work. It's only work with my other code that i don't use SafeArea. Could you help me to slove this problem please.

This is the picture of the issue
[image: the issue]

This is the picture of the portrait screen
[image]

This is my code for showing the detail in screen.

```
  class _DiaryDetailState extends State<DiaryDetail> {
  double xOffset = 0; //set X axis and Y axis
  double yOffset = 0;
  double scaleFactor = 1;
  bool isDrawerOpen = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var width = screenSize.width;
    var height = screenSize.height;
    return 
    AnimatedContainer(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff1a3c5a),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(isDrawerOpen ? 40 : 0.0),
      ),
      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(xOffset, yOffset, 0)
        ..scale(scaleFactor),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    isDrawerOpen
                        ? IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                              color: Color(0xffdac6a3),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(
                                () {
                                  xOffset = 0;
                                  yOffset = 0;
                                  scaleFactor = 1;
                                  isDrawerOpen = false;
                                },
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        : IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.menu,
                              color: Color(0xffdac6a3),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(
                                () {
                                  xOffset = 230;
                                  yOffset = 150;
                                  scaleFactor = 0.6;
                                  isDrawerOpen = true;
                                },
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'My Diary',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 25.0,
                        letterSpacing: 1.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3, right: 3,),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: isDrawerOpen
                        ? BorderRadius.circular(40)
                        : BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(60),
                          ),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    child: DiaryCalenda(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
);
  }
}
```

And this is my code for the orange box that when i rotate and i got some issue. I think the problem can be the first 'cloumn' in Expanded.

```
          Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                  child: Container(
                    // color: Colors.black,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                      color: Color(0xffdac6a3),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 15,
                        left: 30,
                        right: 20,
                      ),
                      child:Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              _selectedToday
                                  ? Text(
                                      "Today",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 25,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : Text(
                                      _showDate,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 25,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                              Container(
                                height: 45,
                                width: 45,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Color(0xffecb45b),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.add,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      size: 20,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(
                                        context, AddEventScreen.routeName),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              child: ListView(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  ..._selectedEvents.map(
                                    (event) => Container(
                                      height: 70,
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Row(
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                Container(
                                                  width: 30.0,
                                                  height: 30.0,
                                                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: Colors.orange,
                                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  width: 40,
                                                ),
                                                Column(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Text(
                                                      event.title,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 18,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.bold,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(DateFormat('jm')
                                                        .format(event.eventDate)
                                                        .toString()),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            IconButton(
                                              icon: Icon(
                                                Icons.arrow_forward,
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                              ),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.push(
                                                  context,
                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (_) =>
                                                        EventDetailsPage(
                                                      event: event,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Thank you for your all answer.

Comment: I would try to adapt the container size of the day boxes to the screen size. But remember to subtract the navigation bar on top from the size. You could for example put all days inside of a single container and then get the size of that container to adjust the height of the day containers

Comment: can you add a portrait screenshot

Comment: I already add code for the orange box which i got the problem. Could you suggest me that where i have to fix it @w461

Comment: @HardikKumar I already add the portrait screen and more code, i think the problem is because the orange box.

Comment: Swapping `SafeArea` and `AnimatedContainer` might help.

Comment: You should try `SingleChildScrollView`